# Rendering per-vertex data to texture (Direct3D 11)

Tags: directx, textures, rendering, hlsl, direct3d11

I generate simple 2D grid with triangle strip representing water surface. First generated vertex has position [0,0] and the last one has [1,1]. For my water simulation I need to store current positions of vertices to a texture and then sample these values from the texture in the next frame to get the previous state of the water surface.

So, I created the texture in a size of vertices. For example if I will have a 10x10 vertices grid, I use a texture with 10x10 pixels (one pixel for one vertex data). And set this texture as a render target to render all vertex data into it.

According to this: [MSDN Coordinate Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), If I will use current positions of vertices in the grid (bottom-left at [0;0], top-right at [1;1]), rendered texture looks like this:

[image]

So I need to do some conversion to NDC. I convert it in a vertex shader like this:

> [vertex.x * 2 - 1; vertex.y * 2 - 1]

Consider this 3x3 grid:

[image]

Now, grid is stretched to whole texture size. Texture coordinates are different from NDC and apparently I can use original coordinates of the grid (before conversion) to sample values from the texture and get previous values (positions) of vertices.

Here is a sample of my vertex/pixel shader code:

This vertex shader converts coordinates and sends it to pixel shader with SV_POSITION semantics (describes the pixel location).

```
struct VertexInput 
{
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

struct VertexOutput 
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

// convertes coordinates from 0,0 origin to -1,-1, etc.
float2 toNDC(float2 px)
{
    return float2(px.x * 2 - 1, px.y * 2 - 1);
}

VertexOutput main( VertexInput input )
{
    VertexOutput output;

    float2 ndc = toNDC(float2(input.pos.x, input.pos.z));

    output.pos = float4(ndc, 1, 1);
    output.tex = float2(input.pos.x, input.pos.z);

    return output;
}
```

And here's the pixel shader saving values from vertex shader at defined pixel location (SV_POSITION).

```
struct PixelInput
{
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD;
};

float4 main(PixelInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(input.tex.x, input.tex.y, 0, 1);
}
```

And we're finally getting to my problem! I use graphics debugger in Visual Studio 2012 which allows me to look at the rendered texture and its values. I would expect that at the pixel location [0,1] (in texel coordinate system) should be value [0,0] (or [0,0,0,1] to be precise, for RGBA format) but it seems that value of final pixel is interpolated between 3 vertices and I have a wrong value for a given vertex.

Screenshot from VS graphics debugger:

Rendered 3x3 texture ([0;1] location in texel coordinate system):

[image]

Values from vertex and pixel shader:

[image]

How to render the exact value from vertex shader to texture for a given pixel?
I am pretty new to computer graphics and Direct3D 11, so please excuse my deficiencies.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to render the vertex buffer itself to a texture (without interpolation)?  Why not just use a texture to begin with?

Comment: As I mentioned before, I'm trying to do a water simulation and vertex buffer isn't the only thing I need to render to a texture (It's more like a test for now). Actually I don't really need a vertex buffer itself but only a Z coordinate indicating a height of a water surface. Next things (values) I will have to store in a texture are pressure, velocity, etc. With these physical quantities I'll be able to compute a motion of a water surface (i.e. Navier–Stokes equations...) But with original coordinates of a grid I should be able to sample these values. Is it wrong my idea of how it might work?

Comment: And another question came to my mind. I always thought vertex shader handles vertices independently. How is it that debugger knows about the other two vertices to triangle? as you can see in the last picture in my main post... I know, it's a debugger, but how this actually works?

Comment: I think the thought of MooseBoys was, why do want to encode you water-state in the vertices and then render them into a texture, but not directly use the texture. You could fill initially a texture with the current state and update every frame this texture with the next computation. The vertex-grid would be transformed in the vertex-shader according to this texture. So you would never have to convert data of you vertices into a texture, because it's always stored in the texture and the vertices are only for representation.

Comment: The rasterizer get three vertices as an input from the vertexshader, otherwise he wouldn't be able to raster the triangle. I think the debugger use this information to show you the vertices in groups. The vertexshader itself, as you said, only know one vertex at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I totaly agree with you MooseBoys and Gnietschow. But only problem is how to render initial values into a texture appropriately. If computation is performed in vertex shader, so for example I've got a new value of a pressure for a given vertex, I have to update this value in a texture (every frame). And, as you said, rasterizer  gets three vertices as an input from vertex shader, so if every vertex has a different value, rasterizer interpolates it by default, right? So a value stored in a texture will be wrong (or not precise). I'm really confused right now :)

Comment: The typical approach for this kind of problem would be to have a vertex buffer that represents a flat uniform grid, and one or more textures to store surface data.  The vertex shader then samples from these textures to perturb the position of the vertices into the fluid's surface.  To update the surface conditions over time (e.g. Navier-Stokes), you could use a compute shader, or a single 1:1 quad (emulating compute with the pixel shader).

Comment: I heard about compute shaders, it should be easier than using texture and pixel shader. But still, can you be more specific how to use a single 1:1 quad? I think this is what I'm trying to do whole time, but  I'm missing something...

Comment: If you want to process a texture as you would with compute, but with a pixel shader, you will create a single quad (2 triangles) spanning range -1 to +1 (x), +1 to -1 (y), 0 to 1 (u), and 0 to 1 (v).  This will invoke one pixel shader thread for every pixel in the target.  Use a point sampler (or .Load()) to load the previous "frame" of data, do some processing, then return the value the next frame should be (writing to the render target). Keep in mind you'll need at least two textures so you can read from the "last" frame and write the "next" frame.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've got it now. Finally :)